# A singleton-like manager class, better design?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I'm making a game engine and I'm using libraries for various tasks. For example, I use FreeType which needs to be initialized, get the manager and after I don't use it I have to de-initialize it. Of course, it can only be initialized once and can only be de-initialized if it has been initialized.

What I came up with (just an example, not "real" code [but could be valid C++ code]):

```
class FreeTypeManager
{
private:
    FreeTypeManager() {} // Can't be instantiated

    static bool initialized;
    static TF_Module * module;  // I know, I have to declare this in a separate .cpp file and I do

public:
    static void Initialize()
    {
        if (initialized) return;

        initialized = true;
        FT_Initialize();
        FT_CreateModule(module);
    }

    static void Deinitialize()
    {
        if (!initialized) return;

        initialized = false;
        FT_DestroyModule(module);
        FT_Deinit();
    }
};
```

And for every manager I create (FreeType, AudioManager, EngineCore, DisplayManager) it's pretty much the same: no instances, just static stuff. I can see this could be a bad design practice to rewrite this skeleton every time. Maybe there's a better solution.

Would it be good to use singletons instead? Or is there a pattern suiting for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want the singleton approach (which kind of makes sense for manager-type objects), then why not make it a *proper* singleton, and have a static `get` function that, if needed, creates the manager object, and have the managers (private) constructor handle the initialization and handle the deinitialization in the destructor (though manager-type objects typically have a lifetime of the whole program, so the destructor will only be called on program exit).

Something like

```
class FreeTypeManager
{
public:
    static FreeTypeManager& get()
    {
        static FreeTypeManager manager;
        return manager;
    }

    // Other public functions needed by the manager, to load fonts etc.
    // Of course non-static

    ~FreeTypeManager()
    {
        // Whatever cleanup is needed
    }

private:
    FreeTypeManager()
    {
        // Whatever initialization is needed
    }

    // Whatever private functions and variables are needed
};
```

---

If you don't want a singleton, and only have static function in the class, you might as well use a `namespace` instead. For variables, put them in an anonymous namespace in the implementation (source) file. Or use an opaque structure pointer for the data (a variant of the *pimpl idiom*).

Comment: That's what I'm going to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's another solution, which isn't exactly singleton pattern, but very related.

```
class FreeTypeManager
{
public:
   FreeTypeManager();
   ~FreeTypeManager();
 };
 class SomeOtherClass
 {
 public:
   SomeOtherClass(FreeTypeManager &m) : m(m) {}
 private:
   FreeTypeManager &m;
 };
 int main() {
    FreeTypeManager m;
    ...
    SomeOtherClass c(m);
 }
```

The solution is to keep it ordinary c++ class, but then just instantiate it at the beginning of main(). This moves initialisation/destruction to a little different place. You'll want to pass references to FreeTypeManager to every class that wants to use it via constructor parameter.

Note that it is important that you use main() instead of some other function; otherwise you get scoping problems which require some thinking how to handle..

Comment: This is something like what I've ended up doing. I made singletons but I have a Controller class in which I store the instances for easy access. Thanks for the tip tho!